# Incompability ListView and Actionbar

Tags: android, android-listview, android-actionbar

I am experiencing problem while using ListView and Actionbar. I use this for the Actionbar:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.maths:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Du bist bereits bei Mathe :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.physics:
            Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(Home.this, ActivityPhysics.class);
            startActivity(myIntent2);
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And it works perfectly. Now I am saying extends list. In list.java I have:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter( new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.single_item, Liste));
    ListView Liste = getListView();
    Liste.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    Liste.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) arg1).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show();
        }

    });
}
```

When I comment (//, /* */) the Actionbar, the Listview works. When I am commenting the Listview, Actionbar works. Both makes a nullpointerexception and "youapp has unexpectly stopped".

Is there any way to get both working? Or am I maybe missing something? :(

Comment: For any object in Android, I've always found that initiating it the normal way is best:
ListView l = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
Also, you are calling your listview (Liste) after you are setting the adapter. Also, can you please add more code, so we can see he action bar?

Comment: I think the problem is, that I said "this, r.layout.single_item, Liste".
There is missing the id of the textview, isn't it?

But it doesn't found my r.id.list. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you saying it is crashing because Eclipse can't find r.layout.single_item? Is this id in your XML?